# Start a Task thread from another Task when a certain time frame passed by

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

How can I start a c# 4.0 Task2 (TPL) from another Task1 after a certain time x seconds?

Sample scenario:

Start Task1 that computing an algo. When the computing took at least X seconds start another Task to show the user a nice animation not blocking the UI.

Comment: Why 'from from another Task` and what does that mean exactly? Does it have to be a Child  Task?

Answer (score 0):

Start first task, `Wait(TimeSpan)` for result. If `Wait` returns `false`, start second task.